Two ellipses of equal area are both tangent to pair of parallel lines, prove that their convex hull contains larger ellipse
Two ellipses of equal area are both tangent to pair of parallel lines as shown on picture, prove that their convex hull contains larger ellipse.
Here (Prove that convex hull of two non-coinciding ellipses of equal area and with coinciding centers contains ellipse of larger area) I proved particular case of this statement, now more general case is considered.


First, we note that if two ellipses of equal area are both tangent to pair of parallel lines, we can apply shear transformation parallel to these lines which does not shift one of these lines and images of these two ellipses become symmetric one to another with respect to line, orthogonal to parallel lines as on picture below. It follows from uniqueness of ellipse tangent to parallel lines at given points and having given volume.

On $picture 1$ below two ellipses $O$ and $O’$ of equal area are symmetric with respect to line $BH$ and touch two parallel lines $AC$ and $GI$, orthogonal to axis of symmetry, at points $A,C,G,I$. $E$ and $F$ are points of intersection of $O$ and $O’$ where $EF$ is parallel to $AC$. The third ellipse $O’’$ is ellipse of the same area as $O$ and $O’$ touching lines $AC$ and $GI$ at points $B$ and $H$.
Because $O$ and $O’$ are images of $O’’$ under shear transformation parallel to $AC$, which does not shift interval $DF$, we conclude that interval of intersection of $O’’$ with any line parallel to $AC$ has same length as intervals of intersection of this line with $O$ and $O’$, thus $O’’$ intersects both $O$ and $O’$ at points $D$ and $F$.
If we denote $E$ the point of intersection of $AI$ and $CG$, which belongs to interval $DF$, we conclude that convex hull of $O$ and $O’$ contains $O’’$ and extends left and right from border of $O’’$ in a direction parallel to $AC$ at least at half width of triangle $AEC$ or triangle $GEI$ at given distance from line $DF$.

$Picture 2$ shows vicinity of point $D$ in details. Line $KJ$ is tangent to $O’’$ at point $D$, distances from $K$ and $J$ to line $DE$ is $h$. Lines $KM, JL$ are parallel to line $AC$, $M$ and $L$ are intersections of theses lines with $O’’$. Points $N$ and $P$ on lines $KM$ and $JL$ are such that $NM = PL = h*tg(∠AEB)$. $Q$ is intersection of $NP$ with $DE$.
Because border of $O’’$ is differentiable, we can find $h$ that small that both $KM<NM/2$ and $JL<NM/2$. Since both $N$ and $P$ are in convex hull of $O$ and $O’$ and so does $Q$, it follows that convex hull of $O$ and $O’$ extends both left and right from ellipse $O’’$ at least at distance $h*tg(∠AEB)/2$ along any line parallel to $AC$ and intersecting $O’’$. This means that we can stretch ellipse $O’’$, that have horizontal half-axis $a$, with ratio $(a + h*tg(∠AEB)/2)/a$ along $AC$ and resulting ellipse will be contained in convex hull of $O$ and $O’$∎
One useful corollary of the above statement is that largest ellipse inscribed into convex set which has axis of symmetry must have one of its half-axes along  axis of symmetry of convex set, otherwise we can claim that symmetric (but not coinciding) ellipse is also inscribed in this convex symmetric set and thus convex hull of these two ellipses, contained in convex set, contains ellipse of larger area.
Another consequence – If convex set has more than two axes of symmetry, the largest ellipse inscribed in this set is circle, as shown on picture below.

